# Word find/replace not being fully lazy

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word

I am using a wildcard find/replace involving the following find field:

`([0-9]*)`

(Please note that there should be a space at the end of the field even though I can't get it to stick on here on SO)

When I search on the text:

`13 April Boon  87 155`

(Just because it's not visually clear here, everything should be tab-separated except for the "87 155" and "April Boon", which have spaces.)

Since post-star is (nominally) a lazy evaluator, I would expect this to match only "87 ".  This is the result that I want!

But it is making 4 matches:
"13 April "
"3  April "
"87 "
"7 "

This is all the more mysterious to me because it is NOT matching "13    April Boon  87 " or "3  April Boon  87 "

What's going on here?  How can I get the match that I seek?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How come you expect it to match `87` but not `13`? Also, `*` is not a lazy nominator, `*?` is, but that isn't producing the issue. You should also get rid of star and use `+` so you don't replace empty spaces.

Comment: The problem is that you're expecting Word to support regular expressions completely when you check the *Use wildcards* box, and it doesn't. It supports limited wildcards and character groups. It does not support regular expressions, and therefore your use of the regex tag is inappropriate. (In fact, your question is actually off-topic here; it belongs on [su] instead, as it's about using Word find and replace and has nothing to do with programming.)

Comment: @AndrisLeduskrasts, there is a tab between 13 and April.

Comment: @KenWhite, I must respectfully disagree that these are not regular expressions.  That strikes me as an overly-narrow definition of regexes.  Besides, Microsoft [clearly identifies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) them as regular expressions.

Comment: They are very weird regular expressions. But you will have 4 matches, they are expected: `[0-9]` matches a digit, followed by any text (`*`) up to the first space. You really have 4 matches. You can only capture `87` with `(<[0-9]@>) <[0-9]@>^13`. However, without knowing what you need to do, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Agree with everyone here. How could a regular expression possibly know you want only `87` when you tell it you want all groups of numbers.

Comment: @stribizhev You fixed my problem.  I was confusing * with @.  Thank you!

Comment: It's a limited set of regex-like features. The fact that MS labels it something doesn't make it fact. They labeled the Zume as the world's greatest MP3 player, remember? :-) It's still not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines, and therefore is still off-topic here. The suggestion to post to [su] instead is still correct; this is a general software question. Unless you're dealing with Word VBA, Word is not a *software tool commonly used by developers*; it's not a code editor, it's not a general purpose regex or grep tool, or anything else other than a word processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wildcard pattern works as expected. Your pattern `([0-9]*)` matches:

- `([0-9]` - (Capture group 1, can be referenced with `\1`) a digit
- `*)` - any characters but as few as possible up to the first...
- - space.

Since matches are found from left to right, you have 4 matches. [0-9] matches a digit.

You can only capture `87` with a regex like `(<[0-9]@>) <[0-9]@>^13`.

- `(<[0-9]@>)` - a whole "word" containing one or more digits
- - a space
- `<[0-9]@>` - a whole "word" containing one or more digits
- `^13` - carriage return

Comment: Since it solved your issue, please consider accepting. If you found it helpful please also consider upvoting.